# Icefaces ehanced multiselection component

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces-3

I search a multiselection component for a JSF2 / Icefaces 3application / Icefaces 3 which have this functionalities : two list selectable and selected with arrows to move an item from one list to the other or all the elements from one list to the other. Somthings like selectManyShuttle

Answer (score 0):

It's ok i found the solutions :http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=aceMenu&exp=listBean